# I would like to mock open an existing test file, apply a function to it for the test, but not change the actual contents of the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a function that updates a rpm spec file for later on use. it has three parameters: the name of the application, the version we want to bump to, and where the spec file lives in the filesystem.

What I can't seem to do is have, say, a tests/files/package_name.spec file and test that it versions it correctly without changing the actual spec file. I don't want to change the actual spec file because it would make the test useless the second time it gets ran.

I have tried looking into the mock library and mock_open but nothing seems to fit this case.

```
def test_update_spec_file():
    update_spec_file("package_name", "5.0.0", "files/package_name")
    with open("files/package_name.spec", "r") as f:
        contents = f.read()
        version_regex = re.compile("^.*define _software_version.*$")
        assert (
            re.search(version_regex, contents).group(0)
            == "%define _software_version 5.0.0"
        )
```

Essentially what the `update_spec_file` function does is find the `%define _software_version 5.0.0` line using regex and use regex again to sub in a new version.

So in conclusion, would it be possible to have the file exist, open it with some sort of mock file with its contents, run the function on that, and assert it did its job without actually modifying the file in the file system?

Either that or reset the file after its modified.

This is the code that updates the spec file:

```
def update_spec_file(application, release_version, path_to_spec_file):
    """Update the spec file with the release version.

    Args:
        application (str): Name of the application.
        release_version (str): New version of application.
        path_to_spec_file (str, optional):
            path the the applications spec file we are modifying.
    """
    print(f"Updating spec file _software_version to {release_version}")

    try:
        with open(path_to_spec_file, "r") as spec_file:
            spec_contents = spec_file.readlines()
    except EnvironmentError:
        print(f"Unable to open spec file located at: {path_to_spec_file}")
        # raise the original exception again.
        raise

    # Find and replace software version in contents of spec file.
    version_regex = re.compile("%define _software_version.*?(?=(?:\\n)|$)")
    define_version = f"%define _software_version {release_version}"
    # Splice the new software version line into the existing file contents
    spec_contents[:] = [
        version_regex.sub(define_version, line) for line in spec_contents
    ]

    try:  # Open the file and write the new spliced contents
        with open(path_to_spec_file, "w") as f_spec_file:
            f_spec_file.writelines(spec_contents)
    except EnvironmentError:  # Catch spec file not found.
        print(f"Unable to open spec file located at: {path_to_spec_file}")
        # raise the original exception again.
        raise
```

edit:

this is the modified code:

```
def test_update_spec_file():
    content = open("tests/files/package_name.spec").read()
    with patch(__name__ + ".open", create=True) as mock_open:
        mock_open.return_value.__enter__.return_value = StringIO(content)
        with open("tests/files/package_name.spec") as f:
            update_spec_file(
                "package_name", "5.0.0", "tests/files/package_name.spec"
```

what i am doing to test it is `cat` the spec file before the test runs, and `cat` after the test runs

the tree structure of the code:

```
release/
├── release_all_in_one
│   ├── changelog_utils.py
│   ├── confluence_email.py
│   ├── confluence_utils.py
│   ├── create_confluence_page.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── jira_utils.py
│   ├── parse_confluence.py
│   ├── parse_rm_objects.py
│   ├── release_all_in_one_openshift.py
│   ├── release_all_in_one.py
│   ├── tag_branch.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── admin_package_template
│   │   ├── base_template
│   │   ├── cdn_package_template
│   │   ├── fe_package_template
│   │   ├── oddjob_package_template
│   │   ├── openshift_template
│   │   └── procedure.json
│   └── utils.py
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── files
    │   └── package_name.spec
    ├── test_changelog.py
    ├── testing_utils.py
    └── test_utils.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `patch` the `open` function to return a context manager that returns a `io.StringIO` object with the content of the actual file:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from io import StringIO
content = '123' # value for demo
# uncomment the line below to read actual file content
# content = open('files/package_name.spec').read()
with patch(__name__ + '.open', create=True) as mock_open:
    mock_open.return_value.__enter__.return_value = StringIO(content)
    with open('files/package_name.spec') as f:
        print(f.read())
        f.seek(0)
        f.write('abc')
        f.seek(0)
        print(f.read())
```

This outputs:

```
123
abc
```

Alternatively, you can assign to `open` a `MagicMock` object instead so that the all references to `open` in the same module gets overridden:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from io import StringIO
content = '123' # value for demo
# uncomment the line below to read actual file content
# content = open('files/package_name.spec').read()
open = MagicMock()
open.return_value.__enter__.return_value = StringIO(content)
with open('files/package_name.spec') as f:
    print(f.read())
    f.seek(0)
    f.write('abc')
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: Hey i appreciate the help, however this still modifies the actual file :\

Comment: Please update your question with your actual code that updates the file. The currently posted code does not modify the file at all.

Comment: added the function in there

Comment: I see. If you want the real functionalities of a file object, you can use an `io.StringIO` object in place of the real file. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: for some reason this still actually modifies the real file. this is way more info than i had previously so i can play around a little more. thank you for the help

Comment: i see in your example it works so its probably something weird in other parts of the code.

Comment: You can update your question with your new code with my solution applied so that I can help see how the solution might be incorrectly applied.

Comment: Is `update_spec_file` in a different module than the module that contains the unit test? If so, you will need to patch the `open` function of that module as well. The demo code prepends `__name__` as the module name of `open`, so you should make it the name of the module that contains `update_spec_file` instead.

Comment: i will try that. it is in the same module. i can post the tree structure real quick.

Comment: added tree structure, and update_spec_file is in changelog_utils.py

Comment: So `update_spec_file` is in `changelog_utils.py`, and the unit test is in a different module, such as `test_changelog.py`? If so, that isn't the "same module" after all, and you will need to patch `open` for that module instead.

Comment: okay that actually worked. thank you for all the time and help.